# Asymptotics for $\sum_{abc \leq x} \dfrac{1}{(abc)^k}$

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

For $m \geq 1$ an integer and $k>0$ a real number, define 
$$F_{k,m}(x) = \sum\limits_{a_1\cdots a_m \leq x} \dfrac{1}{(a_1 \cdots a_m)^k}$$
In particular, we have $$F_{k,3}(x) = \sum\limits_{abc \leq x} \dfrac{1}{(abc)^k}$$
(Here the product is over the $m$-tuples $(a_1, ..., a_m)$ of integers greater than or equal to $1$ such that the product $a_1 \cdots a_m$ is smaller than or equal to $x$).

**My question:** what is the asymptotics of $F_{k,m}(x)$ as $x \to \infty$? At least are there some good upper bounds?

**Ideas:** 
I tried for $m=3$, when $k \neq 1$:
$$F_{k,3}(x) \ll 
\sum_{a \leq x} \sum_{b \leq \frac x {a}} \dfrac{(x/ab)^{-k+1}}{-k+1}
\ll
x^{-k+1} \sum_{a \leq x} \frac 1 a  \sum_{b \leq \frac x {a}} \frac 1 b
\ll
x^{-k+1} \sum_{a \leq x} \frac 1 a \ln(x/a) \leq x^{-k+1} \ln(x) \sum_{a \leq x} \frac 1 a \ll x^{-k+1} \ln(x)^2$$

When $k=1$, I got $F_{1,3}(x) \ll \ln(x)^3$
Apparently we have $F_{1,3}(x) = \dfrac{\ln(x)^3}{6} + O(\ln(x)^2)$. How can I find it? What about the general case for $k>0$ (and for $m>3$)?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the conditions $\left\{\,a_{k}\,\right\}$ satisfy ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin : sorry, I forgot to mention that $a_i \geq 1$ are integers.

Comment: $\huge{\bullet\quad\bullet \atop \smile}$

Answer (score 2):

With $|m|_\times = \prod_{i=1}^l m_i$ $$\zeta(s+k)^l = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^l} |m|_\times^{-s-k} =  s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^l, |m|_\times < x} |m|_\times^{-k}) x^{-s-1}dx$$
By inverse Mellin transform and the residue theorem
$$\begin{eqnarray}\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}^l, |m|_\times < x} |m|_\times^{-k} &=& \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \zeta(s+k)^l\frac{x^s}{s}ds \\ &=& Res(\zeta(s+k)^l\frac{x^s}{s},0)+Res(\zeta(s+k)^l\frac{x^s}{s},1-k)+\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{\frac{l-1}{l}-k+\epsilon-i\infty}^{\frac{l-1}{l}-k+\epsilon+i\infty} \zeta(s+k)^l\frac{x^s}{s}ds \\
 &=& \zeta(k)^l-\frac{(l-1)!}{k-1}x^{1-k} (\log x)^{l-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{l-2} a_{l,k,j}x^{1-k} (\log x)^j+\mathcal{O}(x^{\frac{l-1}{l}-k+\epsilon})\end{eqnarray}$$
Where you'll compute the coefficients $a_{l,k,j}$ in term of $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \gamma_n (s-1)^n$, or for a fixed $l,k$ [using WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Res%5B+Zeta%5Bs%2B5%5D%5E3*+x%5Es%2Fs,+%7Bs,-4%7D%5D)

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a bit difficult to follow for me; could you please elaborate the case $m=3$ (explicitely and directly, if possible, since I don't know Mellin inversion).

Comment: @Alphonse : No I can't. The Mellin inversion and the residue theorem makes things much easier and are the fundamental tools in the theory of $\zeta(s)$ (this is how we prove the prime number theorem). the Mellin transform is just the Laplace/Fourier transform up to a change of variable

Comment: @Alphonse I added a link for the case $l= 3, k = 5$